# Monotouch Augmented Reality

Tags: xamarin.ios, augmented-reality

I'm trying to use the code posted here: http://seanho.posterous.com/monotouch-first-attempt-arkit-c-version

however - when i try to overlay it on a camera - it seems to behave really strangely.

I'm guess that it's because the camera view only does portrait?

Has anyone succesfully used this? Or maybe know's how to get this working?

Cheers

w://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code on the blog entry you linked to is ported from the open source iPhone ARKit: http://www.iphonear.org/

iPhone ARKit was updated after this port was posted (to quote the author "My version of code may be outdated").  You may want to examine the source on github to pick up any changes/fixes.

Comment: i'm planning on getting back into this in the new year - will report back :)